# WordPress event booking system with linked products

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a website that runs an event everyday, each event has linked products to it, which has a limited number of availability for each day.

Can someone recommend a plugin that can fulfil this requirement.
-Admin can create an event that doesn't have to be added as a new product each day of the year..
-Products can be linked to the event with a limited availability.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can find the plugin that you like here: https://codecanyon.net/popular_item/by_category?category=wordpress/calendars

BTW, I think stackoverflow is not a place for these kind of questions.